# TypeError: Object of type Cursor is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, mongodb, api, flask

I'm creating a solar system application and having issues with the routing. I'm creating this app through with flask and using mongodb as a database.

I've made sure that the files inserted into mongodb are json files and yet I receive the same error for all three routes. I've tried iterating through each doc in each collection and I've tried json dumping. Neither has worked. Any ideas?

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, json, send_from_directory, request, jsonify
from flask.templating import render_template
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
from flask_cors import CORS #comment this on deployment
from api.HelloApiHandler import HelloApiHandler
from  pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='Solar-System-Education\client\build')
CORS(app) #comment this on deployment
api = Api(app)

client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@capstone.tbgw0.mongodb.net/Capstone?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.Capstone
planet_blurb = db.planet_descriptions
quiz_questions = db.quizzes
planet_stats = db.planets_info

@app.route("/Planets", methods = ['GET'])
def getplanetinfo():
    planets = (planet_stats.find())
    return jsonify(planets)

@app.route("/Quiz", methods = ["GET"])
def getquizquestions():
    quizzes = (quiz_questions.find())
    return jsonify(quizzes)

@app.route("/Planets", methods = ["GET"])
def getplanet_descriptions():
    descriptions = (planet_blurb.find())
    return jsonify(descriptions)



@app.route("/", defaults={'path':''})
def serve(path):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder,'index.html')

api.add_resource(HelloApiHandler, '/flask/hello')
```

And just in case: **HelloApiHandler.py**

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

class HelloApiHandler(Resource):
  def get(self):
    return {
      'resultStatus': 'SUCCESS',
      'message': "Hello Api Handler"
      }

  def post(self):
    print(self)
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('type', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('message', type=str)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args)
    # note, the post req from frontend needs to match the strings here (e.g. 'type and 'message')

    request_type = args['type']
    request_json = args['message']
    # ret_status, ret_msg = ReturnData(request_type, request_json)
    # currently just returning the req straight
    ret_status = request_type
    ret_msg = request_json

    if ret_msg:
      message = "Your Message Requested: {}".format(ret_msg)
    else:
      message = "No Msg"
    
    final_ret = {"status": "Success", "message": message}

    return final_ret
```

[full error details as requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FzkG.png)

Comment: add full error details please.

Comment: i've edited the post to reflect that @balderman

Answer (score 5):

pymongo's `.find()` returns a cursor object, hence the error you are seeing. You need to convert it to a list before passing it to `jsonify()`; but be careful, if the returned document contains non-standard types (such as `ObjectId`), this would give a similar error. Consider using the `bson.json_util.dumps()` which supports json serialisation for all MongoDB types.

This would be an improvement on what you have:

```
@app.route("/Planets", methods = ['GET'])
def getplanetinfo():
    planets = planet_stats.find({}, {'_id': 0})
    return jsonify(list(planets))
```

Answer (score 0):

`return jsonify(descriptions)` is the problematic line. Before you call the return do `print(descriptions)`. You will find out that one the fields in descriptions is a cursor. Give it a try. Your job will be to remove the cursor before you call `jsonify`